# Why doesn't Python 3 install python3 into a virtual environment by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Stupid question time.  I am running Debian 9 and have python, python3, and virtualenv all installed in `/usr/bin`.  So I run the following command to create a virtual environment `venv` in my current directory:

```
 python3 -m virtualenv venv
```

When I do this, it installs python2 into `./venv/bin`.

```
 which python    # ./venv/bin/python
 python -V       # Python 2.7.13
 which python3   # /usr/bin/python3
```

If I'm building a virtual environment with the Python 3 interpreter, why doesn't Python install python3 into the new environment by default?  I would think that Python would assume that if I'm using Python 3 to build the environment, I want python3 to be the default Python in it.  I know I can specify the `--python /usr/bin/python3` to have this occur, but that seems counter-intuitive and extra work.  If you build an environment with Python 2, install Python 2 into it and if you build with Python 3, then install Python 3 into the environment.  Simple.  Can anyone explain the rationale here, particular since Python 2 support ends in 2020?

Comment: ```which ./python``` returns ```.python``` as you would expect.  It's still python2.  If you just list the bin directory, you see that python2 is installed and there are python and python2.7 symbolic links that both point to it.  Python 2 is definitely being installed into the "venv" subdirectory.

Comment: Did you run `source [venv]/bin/activate`?

Comment: @yahocho Yes I did.  This is all pretty straightforward but the results aren't what I expected.

Comment: What does **`python3 -V`** return? As a workaround, you could try: `python3 -m virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv`.

Comment: It's *supposed* to use the same Python interpreter you used to run `virtualenv`. Your Python setup may be screwed up somehow.

Comment: `which python` forces a `PATH` lookup. However, `python -V` may be using your shell's cached path for `python` from before you activated the virtual environment. Have you checked `./venv/bin/python -V`?

Comment: @chepner Yes and it's Python 2, not Python 3.